# How to Change Base class of Designer generated class from System.Windows.Forms.Form to my own BaseForm

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, code-generation, designer

Everytime I add a new Form to my WinForms project, the designer generates code of a new class which inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Form.

For some reason, I want it to inherit from my own BaseForm class. Any way to automate it other than editing the generated file myself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a scenario that Visual Studio supports directly.  From your project add a new item.  From the dialog that is displayed select "Inherited Form."  The next window should let you select the base form you want to use for your new form.